# Serenity BDD with jUnit how to inject steps into setup method?

Tags: selenium, junit, bdd, thucydides, serenity-bdd

I am working on a test framework which is using Serenity, Selenium and jUnit. I have some tests which depend on user authentication. Basically I have to repeat all login steps for each test. I wanted to move these steps to a @Before method, but it seems that Steps are not being initialized in a method which is not annotated as @Test... See the code snippet below, AuthSteps instance is not being initialized.

Which are my options?

```
@RunWith(SerenityRunner.class)
public class MyTests extends AbstractTest {
@Managed(driver = "firefox", uniqueSession = false)
@Steps
AuthSteps auth;

@Before
public void authSetup() {
 if (!authenticated){
  auth.login();
  //a lot of other things
 }
}

@Test
public void mytest(){
 //do test related stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do. Steps will run with either @BeforeClass, @Before, @Test and so on. It seems that your `if (!authenticated)` statement might be excluding execution of your `auth.login()` step.

There's certainly not enough code provided here (like what is `boolean authenticated`)to clearly examine your issue, but I hope this answer helps you.

Comment: Yes, it seems the problem was completely elsewhere, I managed to place the @Managed annotation in the wrong place... Embarassing.

Comment: Correct, for those with similar issues, it should be something like:

`@Managed(driver = "firefox", uniqueSession = false)
static WebDriver driver;`

Comment: I can definitely not access my `@Steps` in the `@BeforeClass` method. It is null. It does work afterwards though. So I guess it is not yet injected.